# kill process from the same directory

Tags: c, linux, file, process

I'm participate in a contest, in this contest I need to kill processes that run with my program in the same directory. the programming language does not matter it can be any language that working on linux, I choose C because it the language I know the best (if you have another language to do this I'll be happy to hear).

I know that I can kill process with the kill function but I have no idea how to get the id of process in the directory and than kill him.
In addition my program need to defend her self and not to be killed.

How can I do something like this in the best way ?

Comment: What the heck do you mean with a process that runs "in the same directory"? Do you mean that you want to traverse the directory your program is located in and kill all running instances of programs that can be found in this directory? You need to be way more specific.

Comment: I mean that all of the programs are located in tmp directory including my program and from their I need to kill them like I explain above.

Comment: **Your question doesn't make it clear which relation between processes and directories you're referring to - Please improve it.** The binary that was used to create/launch the process reside in a directory. Is that what you mean by "processes that run with me in the same directory"? Other possible relations are the process pid file that normally resides in a subdirectory inside `/proc`, or maybe the directory that a program uses as a chroot environment.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to kill programs that are started in the same directory, you can use the `/proc` folder to determine those.

```
pwd=$(readlink -f .)
cd /proc
for i in *; do
  [ "$(readlink -f $i/cwd)" == "$pwd" ] && kill $i;
done
```

Comment: `cwd` is the current working directory. Open a shell, find out its PID then `cd` into another directory and watch the process' `cwd` link change. `exe` is what you probably want (I mean you want the `dirname` of it).

Comment: @DarkDust, that depends on how do you interpret the question as @jweyrich pointed out. If you want to find programs running in a folder then they are the ones with `cwd` set to that folder. If you want to find programs from that folder that are running then it's the `exe` thing.